# Google app engine and primefaces layout/layoutunit does not work

Tags: google-app-engine, primefaces

I'm working with primefaces and google app engine. I am posting this code because the layouts do not work.
Initially I tried to use the template facelets (composition, include, insert, sets) and neither worked. I am familiar with facelets and jsf as work with them in another environment.
So I decided to try the layout and layouunit, but nothing.

Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"


 xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
   xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
   xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
   xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<f:view contentType="text/html">

<head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
   <title>Inicio</title>
</head>
   <h:body>
      <p:layout fullPage="true">
         <p:layoutUnit position="top" height="75" header="Top">
            <h:outputText value="North unit content1aaaa." />
         </p:layoutUnit>

         <p:layoutUnit position="center">
            <h:form>
              This fullPage layout consists of five different layoutUnits which are                
                 resizable and closable by default.
              </h:form>
         </p:layoutUnit>

         <p:layoutUnit position="bottom" height="75" header="Bottom">
            <h:outputText value="South unit content." />
         </p:layoutUnit>
      </p:layout>
   </h:body>
</f:view>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have some Errors in your Code.

The value of LayoutUnits must not be top or bottom. Allowed values are:

```
<p:layoutUnit position="north"/>
<p:layoutUnit position="west"/>
<p:layoutUnit position="east"/>
<p:layoutUnit position="south"/>
```

Second thing is about

```
<f:view contentType="text/html">
```

Don't include all your content under this Tag. Just close it directly (if it's really needed)

```
<f:view contentType="text/html"/>
```

Then you have to edit your head Tags to

```
<h:head>...</h:head>
```

Just refer to the Primefaces Example: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/layoutFull.jsf

Here's your working Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">


<h:head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>Inicio</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>
  <p:layout fullPage="true">
     <p:layoutUnit position="north" height="75" header="Top">
        <h:outputText value="North unit content1aaaa." />
     </p:layoutUnit>

     <p:layoutUnit position="center">
        <h:form>
          This fullPage layout consists of five different layoutUnits which are                
             resizable and closable by default.
          </h:form>
     </p:layoutUnit>

     <p:layoutUnit position="south" height="75" header="Bottom">
        <h:outputText value="South unit content." />
     </p:layoutUnit>
  </p:layout>
 </h:body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked perfectly. But my code was based on the example of the use case for GAE primeface [link](http://primefaces-rocks.appspot.com/ui/layoutFull.jsf).